# Highlight values based on a range of values. Excel

Tags: vba, excel

In excel, in a range of cells (say A1 to A100) highlight only values that contain any of  the values in a specified range (say A101 to 150). Duplicates among A1 to A100 SHOULD NOT be highlighted. Anybody has a solution?

Comment: Use conditional formatting.  with the formula: `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,$A$101:$A$150,0))` and make the Applies To: reference $A$1:$A$100.

Comment: applies to? where is this option?

Comment: Highlight A1:A100 and create a new conditional format rule and the Applies To will automatically be populated.

Comment: My case here is, I have column A, (A2:A15893) where there are several unique as well as dupes. Column B (B2:B15893) is the reference to A. Again this set will have dupes & unique values. Now, I add a unique set of look up values (B15895:B15924). I want to highlight the duplicate values in B "only" if they are present in the in any of B15895:B15924. I don't want to highlight values in B (B2:B15893) that are duped among themselves but not present in that look up set- B15895:B15924 .

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  Select B2:B15893 > go to conditional formatting 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format' > enter formula `=AND(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$15893,B2)>1,COUNTIF($B$15895:$B$15924,B2)>0)` > Format as Yellow fill > Click OK.

The first logic test in the `AND()` function tests if the value is a duplicate in range $B$2:$B$15893 and the second test if the value also exists in the range of values at the bottom.  If both logic tests are true then the value will be highlighted.

Here is a screenshot of a smaller example.  Hope this helps!

[image: CRUTER.com Conditional Formatting COUNTIF() example]

Comment: It highlights only all the duplicates within B2 to B15893!

Comment: Yeah, that definitely wasn't right...  The updated formula should do.

Comment: Tried this one. It doesn't work! Even in your example, 1004 & 1005 in B6 & B7 should have been highlighted!

Comment: just change `>1` to `>0`.  The formula should look like this: `=AND(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$15893,B2)>0,COUNTIF($B$15895:$B$15924,B2)>0)`.  I thought you only wanted duplicates highlighted.  This will highlight items in your unique list that are either duplicate or unique in the large list.

Comment: Or you could simplify the formula to just: `=COUNTIF($B$15895:$B$15924,B‌​2)>0`